# Set layout from module controller in yii2

Tags: php, layout, view, yii2

I have three layouts in my layouts folder in main views folder. I added a module called subDomain. In my subDomain module I have a Controller called HomeController. In HomeController there is an action called `getDomain()`.

In the `getDomain()` action I want to change the main layout to `getDomainLayout`. But there is an error when I use a code:

`$this->layout = "getDomainLayout";`

Yii2 throws:

```
Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException    
The view file does not exist: \myyii2\modules\subDomain\views\layouts\bersih.php
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are several options to address this issue.

### Create a layout file in the appropriate module directory

An example below shows a canonical directory structure of some `subDomain` module, including it's layouts (domain.php):

```
subDomain/
    Module.php                the module class file
    controllers/              containing controller class files
        HomeController.php    the home controller class file
    models/                   containing model class files
    views/                    containing controller view and layout files
        layouts/              containing layout view files
            domain.php        the domain layout file
        home/                 containing view files for HomeController
            index.php         the index view file
```

Following this simple structure, you can set any layout by its name within the module's controller:

```
namespace myApp\modules\subDomain\controllers;

class HomeController extends Controller {
    public function actionGetDomain() {            
        $this->layout = 'domain'; // equals 'myApp/modules/subDomain/views/layouts/domain'
    }
}
```

This is the most preferable way, because modules are self-contained software units that consist of its own models, layouts, controllers, etc.

### Specify the complete path to the directory that contains your layout file

In some cases you might want to use a layout file that is located outside the module directory:

```
class HomeController extends Controller {
    public function actionGetDomain() {
        $this->layout = '@app/views/layouts/main';
    }
}
```

Where *[@app](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app/#hh0)* is the base path of the currently running application, for example:

```
myApp/frontend
```

In this situation, be sure that the **main.php** layout file exists in the following directory:

```
myApp/frontend/views/layouts/main.php
```

Comment: Setting `$this->layout` in the controller before rendering the template did not work for me. Maybe because it was a .twig template?

Answer (score 6):

If I need different layout in controller, I simple add the following code

```
 public function beforeAction($action)
 {
    $this->layout = 'layout'; //your layout name
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
 }
```

be sure that your layout is exists in appropriate folder

```
'@app/views/layouts/layout.php'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set the variable in the controller.

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
     public $layout = 'main.php';
}
```

Or by passing the complete path

```
public $layout = '@frontend/modules/idModule/views/layouts/main.php';
```

Answer (score 3):

Another one convenient way of using different layouts in your application is to create an abstract class. For example:

```
abstract class AdminBaseController extends Controller
{
    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        $this->layout = '@app/views/admin/layouts/main.php';
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
    ...
}
```

And then just `extends` your controller.

```
class ArticlesController extends AdminBaseController { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set it by default inside the module you can do that by writing

```
$this->layout   =   '@frontend/modules/user/views/layouts/main';
```

inside the `init()` function of your module class your complete code will look like following

```
 public function init() {

    parent::init();
    $this->layout = '@frontend/modules/user/views/layouts/main';
    // custom initialization code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add $this->layout = 'main'; in the module init method. The main.php should be located inside the modules view folder under layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can set the `layout` property in `construtor` like the following:

```
class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct($id, $module, $config = array()) {
    parent::__construct($id, $module, $config);
    $this->layout='main4articles';
  }
....
```